# QTableWidget in VBoxLayout Does not Resize

Tags: qt

I have the following snippet:

```
PDFViewer::PDFViewer(const QString &title, MainWindow *mainWindow, Qt::WindowFlags flags) :
    QDockWidget(title, mainWindow, flags),

    mainWindow_(mainWindow)
{
    setObjectName("PDFViewer");

    setAllowedAreas(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea | Qt::RightDockWidgetArea);

    layoutWidget_ = new QWidget(this);
    verticalLayout_ = new QVBoxLayout(layoutWidget_);

    variable_ = new QLabel(layoutWidget_);
    time_ = new QLabel(layoutWidget_);
    PDFTable_ = new PDFTable(mainWindow_, layoutWidget_);
    PDFPlot_ = new QWidget(layoutWidget_);

    verticalLayout_->addWidget(variable_, 0, Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
    verticalLayout_->addWidget(time_, 0, Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
    verticalLayout_->addWidget(PDFTable_, 1, Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
    verticalLayout_->addWidget(PDFPlot_, 1, Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);

    PDFTable_->horizontalHeader()->hide();
    PDFTable_->verticalHeader()->hide();
    PDFTable_->setAlternatingRowColors(true);
    PDFTable_->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Minimum);

    layoutWidget_->setLayout(verticalLayout_);

    setWidget(layoutWidget_);
}
```

The result is this:

[image]

My problem is that when I change the size of dock window, my table width stays the same. Any idea how to keep the table width the size of the dock/layout?

Answer (score 0):

1. The `Minimum` size policies set on the table may prevent it from expanding. If you want it to expand, set both size policies to `MinimumExpanding`.
2. When you create a layout that has `widget` as a parent, that layout becomes set on `widget`. There's no need to call `widget->setLayout`.
3. When you add widgets to a layout, they will be reparented as soon as the layout is set on a widget, or immediately if the layout is already set on a widget. Thus you don't have to pass parent widgets to `variable_`, `time_`, etc.

The remaining problems are bound to be in the implementation of `PDFTable_` - we'd need to see that to know why it misbehaves. To confirm it, replace `PDFTable_` with a `QWidget` - if the code behaves

Your code could be simplified as below, with `QWidget` inserted for testing purposes:

```
setObjectName("PDFViewer");

setAllowedAreas(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea | Qt::RightDockWidgetArea);

layoutWidget_ = new QWidget(this);
verticalLayout_ = new QVBoxLayout(layoutWidget_);

variable_ = new QLabel();
time_ = new QLabel();
PDFTable_ = new QWidget(); //(mainWindow_);
PDFPlot_ = new QWidget();

verticalLayout_->addWidget(variable_, 0, Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
verticalLayout_->addWidget(time_, 0, Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
verticalLayout_->addWidget(PDFTable_, 1, Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
verticalLayout_->addWidget(PDFPlot_, 1, Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);

#if 0
PDFTable_->horizontalHeader()->hide();
PDFTable_->verticalHeader()->hide();
PDFTable_->setAlternatingRowColors(true);
#endif
PDFTable_->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding);
PDFTable_->setStyleSheet("background: yellow"); // to see it

setWidget(layoutWidget_);
```

Comment: Did your change, thanks (learned about the classes I'm using), but table still doesn't resize when I resize the dock...

Comment: @major4x When you use the substitute `QWidget` instead of the real table, does it still behave that way?